# in spring boot + rest docs, how to set '.html' suffix

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-restdocs

this is example repository.

https://github.com/JYK0128/Debug-Projects/tree/master/Spring_RestDocs_Example

I try to Make resolver bean OR Set Profiles.

I did mapping resource. just in cases.

---

try first.

```
application.properties
...
#spring.mvc.view.prefix=/static/docs/
#spring.mvc.view.suffix=.html
...
```

try second.

```
@Configuration
public class DocsConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    // In spring boot classpath, have '/static', '/public', '/resources' and '/META-INF/resources'
    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/docs/**")
                .addResourceLocations("classpath:/static/docs/");
    }

    @Bean
    public InternalResourceViewResolver internalResourceViewResolver() {
        InternalResourceViewResolver internalResourceViewResolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        internalResourceViewResolver.setPrefix("/static/");
        internalResourceViewResolver.setSuffix(".html");
        return internalResourceViewResolver;
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Can you show us your code, both your Java code and any XML, properties or YAML files you might have?

Comment: @Steve ok. I post it just.

Answer (score 0):

with resource handler, you can map any request with a directory in you app

```
     @Bean
     WebMvcConfigurer webMvcConfigurer(){
            return new WebMvcConfigurerAdapter() {
                @Override
                public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
                    registry.addResourceHandler("/directory_name/**")
                            .addResourceLocations("classpath:/directory_name/");
                }
            };
     }


        @Bean
        public ViewResolver viewResolver() {
            InternalResourceViewResolver resolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
            resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");
            **resolver.setSuffix(".html");**
            resolver.setExposeContextBeansAsAttributes(true);
            return resolver;
        }
```